# How to omit aggregated row when columns are null

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, pivot

I have an EAV table that I'm pivoting into a few columns.

I'd like to not return a row if `[h1]`, `[h2]`, and `[h3]` are all `null`.

```
declare 
@h1 nvarchar(10) = 'A',
@h2 nvarchar(10) = 'B',
@h3 nvarchar(10) = 'C'

select 
[id],
[h1]  = isNull(max( case when [key] = @h1 then [value] end ), ''),
[h2]  = isNull(max( case when [key] = @h2 then [value] end ), ''),
[h3]  = isNull(max( case when [key] = @h3 then [value] end ), ''),
from some..db
group by [id]
having (
  and max( case when [key] = @h1 then [value] end) is not null
  and max( case when [key] = @h2 then [value] end) is not null
  and max( case when [key] = @h3 then [value] end) is not null
)
```

How can I pivot this table and remove rows that have `null` values in the `[h]` columns?

Comment: I'm a bit lost.  You are using `isnull()` so none of the returned values are `NULL`.

Comment: I thought since I am re-evaluating in the `having` clause that the `isnull()` would be ignored. Would `<> ''` in the `having` clause solve this?

Comment: No `<> ''` won't work, and don't use `ISNULL` in the `HAVING`, just change `OR` to `AND`

Comment: *I'd like to not return a row if <column list> are all null* - So just directly translate it to filter: `not(col1 is null and col2 is null and col3 is null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on feedback from `@Charlieface`.

```
declare 
@h1 nvarchar(10) = 'A',
@h2 nvarchar(10) = 'B',
@h3 nvarchar(10) = 'C'

select 
[id],
[h1]  = isNull(max( case when [key] = @h1 then [value] end ), ''), 
[h2]  = isNull(max( case when [key] = @h2 then [value] end ), ''),
[h3]  = isNull(max( case when [key] = @h3 then [value] end ), ''),
from some..db
group by [id]
having (
  max( case when [key] = @h1 then [value] end) is not null
  or max( case when [key] = @h2 then [value] end) is not null
  or max( case when [key] = @h3 then [value] end) is not null
)
```

Or an alternative `having` clause via `@astentx`

```
having max(case when [key] in (@h1, @h2, @h3) then 1 end) is not null
```

Comment: Since you need to find *any* not null, this may be simplified to `having max(case when [key] in (@h1, @h2, @h3) then 1 end) is not null`, because this `case` expression will check if any value of interest exists. Just  not to copy-paste. Or use `pivot` and directly filter `coalesce([h1], [h2], [h3]) is not null`